# Producing sine wave visual gratings on Android

Tags: android, animation

For a project that I'm developing for use on Android tablets, I have to create moving visual sine-wave gratings. Here is an example of such:

[image: Sine wave gratings]

(These are stationary analogues of course.)

I need to be able to modify parameters such as speed, orientation, contrast and spatial frequency. Being able to use different types of gratings as opposed to just linear ones would be a plus (eg. a circular ripple effect).

Could someone offer a suggestion of how I would implement this in Android? Thanks.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow (...)`

Comment: @njkz2 I've rectified the question to meet that criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to map the sine function from `[-1,1]` to `[0,1]` to match the color value range. Then in OpenGL (OpenGL ES), create a plane that represents one single cycle of the sine wave. That is, for this plane the color goes from black to white then black (or white black white). Notice that you need to tile this plane horizontally (perpendicular to the strips), so you need to adjust the proportion of the gradient accordingly.

For painting the colors, you have your moved sine function, and you can simply map `[0,1]` to the RGB 3-tuple `(255,255,255)`, where you multiply your sine value `i` with the tuple and get `(255*i, 255*i, 255*i)` as your color. When `i=1` you get pure white, and `i=0` for pure black.

If you want to set contrast such that you get a wide band of pure white, you need to scale your sine function on the `y` axis, and apply a `[0,1]` bound to the function, such that all sine values bigger than `1` will be forced to `1` by a ceiling, and the same is true for `0`.

For spatial frequency you just need to define the width of that plane.

For speed you define the animation speed of that plane.

Besides using Android OpenGL ES (the above suggestion), I don't think you can get that much flexibility with the built-in features of Android SDK. Also, the ripple grating is much harder than the linear ones. Right now the easy way I can think of is to paint a ball and have an orthographic camera looking from top.

On the other hand if you don't mind pixelation then you can simply make a `Drawable` and do scaling and animation on that. Also the new Android Lollipop now supports vector images as `Drawable`s so you can also check that out.

Comment: In regards to the speed, what do you mean by define the animation speed? How do I get the planes to move on each frame?

Comment: @Gaessaki if you are using GL then you define the plane's position on each refresh loop.